# Как работает оператор запятая?

Tags: c++, c, операторы, стандарт

Почему

```
delete a, b            //освобождает только a
int a, b;              //создаст два int
return a = 1, b = 2;   //вернет 2
```

Везде оператор запятая, однако работает по-разному

Comment: `int a, b;` не содержит оператора запятая, это объявление, в других случаях оператор будет выполняться в соответствии со своим приоритетом, если не уверены - задавайте приоритет явно посредством круглых скобок.

Answer (score 7):

```
delete a, b;
```

Приоритет `delete` выше, поэтому это выражение рассматривается как

```
delete a;
b;
```

Тут

```
int a, b;
```

это *не* оператор "запятая", так же, как не оператор "запятая" и в, скажем, вызове

```
pow(x,y);
```

Здесь

```
return a = 1, b = 2;
```

`return` возвращает выражение `a = 1, b = 2`, которое рассматривается как

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
```

при этом *значением* всего выражения становится значение последнего подвыражения - `b = 2`, т.е. двойка...