# Предупреждение C6031 Возвращаемое значение пропущено: "exp"

Tags: c++

Жалуется на log и exp
Возвращаемое значение пропущено: "exp"
Возвращаемое значение пропущено: "log"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ukrainian");
    double x;
    float G;
    cout << "Введіть x: ";
    cin >> x;
    G = 8,5*exp(-2*x)+((5*(x+4)+log(fabs((x-0,2))))/(x + 2)*(x-0,6));
    cout << "Відповідь: " << G;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А под `8, 5 *...` что имелось в виду?

Comment: 8,5*exp(-2*x) - это просто число умноженное на экспоненту

Comment: Таки попробуйте запятые на точки поменять =)

Comment: Запятая — это не разделитель целой и дробной частей в литерале, а отдельный [оператор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). [Пример](https://ideone.com/emLXxz).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает оператор запятая?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139616/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, ваш код компилируется без проблем. Об ошибке говорит *анализатор кода*, который, кстати, может и ошибаться. Это не компилятор.

А вот компилятор все скомпилирует. Только даст не то, что вы хотите. Потому что запятая получается не десятичной запятой (в С++ эту роль выполняет точка), а [оператором запятая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139616/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F).

В результате ваше выражение

```
G = 8,5*exp(-2*x)+((5*(x+4)+log(fabs((x-0,2))))/(x + 2)*(x-0,6));
```

компилятор рассматривает как два:

```
G = 8;
5*exp(-2*x)+((5*(x+4)+log(fabs((2))))/(x+2)*6));
```

Чтобы оно делало то, что хотите вы - надо написать

```
G = 8.5*exp(-2*x)+((5*(x+4)+log(fabs((x-0.2))))/(x + 2)*(x-0.6));
```

Comment: У оператора запятая приоритет ниже чем у оператора присваивания. Поэтому компилятор рассматривает выражение как `(G = 8), (5 * exp.....)`. Сперва `G` получила значение `8`, затем посчиталось огроменное выражение после запятой. Но результат вычислений после запятой никак не используется. О чём и предупреждает анализатор. [Пример](https://ideone.com/gpH5L0).

Comment: @wololo Да, напутал, сспасибо за исправление. нечасто с запятой приходится дело иметь.